Synchronization Service Manager FIM, Management Agent Extension Error connector is read-only
I'm trying to remove the connection between AD and SQL DB when the employee id is different, but no matter how I'm doing this, this error shows up

connector is read-only
Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.ReadOnlyConnectorServices.Deprovision()
Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.ConnectorImpl.Deprovision() w
Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.ConnectorCollectionImpl.DeprovisionAll()
Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.ConnectedMACollectionImpl.DeprovisionAll()
w
Mms_ManagementAgent_extensionTest.MAExtensionObject.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMASynchronization.MapAttributesForImport(String
FlowRuleName, CSEntry csentry, MVEntry mventry) w
Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.Impl.ScriptHost.InvokeMA_FlowCSToMV(_OCTET
octCSPreImage, _OCTET octCSDelta, _OCTET octMVPreImage, _OCTET
octMVDelta, UInt32 nMappings, _AttributeFlowMapping* rgMappings,
_OCTET* poctMVChanges, _MappingResults* pMappingResults, Int32* pOverallResult) InnerException=> none

Code:
case "EmployeeIDValidation":
    if (mventry.ConnectedMAs["ad-test"].Connectors.Count > 0){
        if (mventry["employeeIDtst"].IsPresent && mventry["employeeIDad"].IsPresent){

            string employeeIDtst = mventry["employeeIDtst"].Value;
            string employeeIDad = mventry["employeeIDad"].Value;

            if (employeeIDtst != employeeIDad){
                mventry.ConnectedMAs.DeprovisionAll();
            }
        }
    }
    break;

